# Onbackpress using navigation graph

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fragment, android-navigation-graph

I have 5 fragment as follows:

[image]

But I want when I am on 5th fragment, when I press back button it returns to 2nd fragment. So how do I do it while I use **navigation graph**

Comment: Are you saying that when you go from 4 to 5, it currently goes back to 4 and you want to change that to going back to 2? Or that it currently goes back to 2 and you want to instead have it go back to 4? Can you include your navigation graph and how to go from 4 to 5?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simply way you can do that by `navigate` the `action` with `popUpTo` from `NavController` in `onBackPressed()` instead of `super.onBackPressed()`.

example:

```
<action android:id="@+id/action_5_to_2"
      app:popUpTo="@id/destination_2" />
```

```
override fun onBackPressed(){
    ...
    findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_5_to_2)
    ...
}
```

And you may want to add `app:popUpToInclusive` as also.

You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) to get further information

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to code your back button like this.

```
    // Your back button
    onBackPressButton.setOnClickListener {

    // intent says that this @FifthFragment/CurrentActivity is going to do something with @SecondFragment/@NextActivity
    val intent = Intent(this@FifthFragment, SecondFragment::class.java)

    // The intent.flags tells to clear the @FifthFragment/@CurrentActivity and start @SecondFragment/@NextActiviy
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    // startActivity starts your intent 
    startActivity(intent)
    }
```